# Retrieving data from xml using xmlDocument, xmlNode and xmlNodelist

Tags: vb.net

This is a sample code in vb.net in which i retrieve the details of elements without attributes.

```
For Each standardItemInfoNode In ItemInfoNodes
        baseDataNodes = ItemInfoNodes.ChildNodes
        bFirstInRow = True
        For Each baseDataNode As XmlNode In baseDataNodes
            If (bFirstInRow) Then
                bFirstInRow = False
            Else
                Response.Write("<br>")
            End If
            Response.Write(baseDataNode.Name & ": " & baseDataNode.InnerText)
        Next
    Next
```

How can i retrieve the details of the xml like having node with attributes and its child also having attributes. I need to retrieve all the attributes of node and its child node which are present in the middle of other xml tags.

Comment: Can you provide an example XML document illustrating what you are talking about?  By the way, if you simply transforming an XML document to a differently formatted output HTML or XML document, I would strongly suggest you look at using an XSLT script and the `XslCompiledTransform` class to transform the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you're asking, and I can't give you a specific example without knowing the format of the XML you are trying to process, but I think what you are looking for is the Attributes property of the XmlNode objects.  Each XmlNode has an Attributes property that allows you to access all the attributes for that node.  Here's the MSDN page that explains it (and provides a simple example):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f285y48.aspx

EDIT:

Using the example XML you posted in the comment, you could read the all the values and attributes like this:

```
    Dim doc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
    doc.LoadXml("<EventTracker><StandardItem><Header1>Header1 Text</Header1> <Header2>Header2 Text</Header2></StandardItem><Item> <Events> <EventSub EventId='73' EventName='Orchestra' Description='0'> <Person PersonId='189323156' PersonName='Chandra' Address='Arunachal'/><Person PersonId='189323172' PersonName='Sekhar' Address='Himachal'/></EventSub> </Events> </Item> </EventTracker>")
    Dim header1 As String = doc.SelectSingleNode("EventTracker/StandardItem/Header1").InnerText
    Dim header2 As String = doc.SelectSingleNode("EventTracker/StandardItem/Header2").InnerText
    For Each eventSubNode As XmlNode In doc.SelectNodes("EventTracker/Item/Events/EventSub")
        Dim eventId As String = eventSubNode.Attributes("EventId").InnerText
        Dim eventName As String = eventSubNode.Attributes("EventName").InnerText
        Dim eventDescription As String = eventSubNode.Attributes("Description").InnerText
        For Each personNode As XmlNode In eventSubNode.SelectNodes("Person")
            Dim personId As String = personNode.Attributes("PersonId").InnerText
            Dim personName As String = personNode.Attributes("PersonName").InnerText
            Dim personAddress As String = personNode.Attributes("Address").InnerText
        Next
    Next
```

However, if you are loading all the data in the XML like this, I would recommend deserializing the XML into an EventTracker object.  Or, as I said in my comment on your post, if the only purpose for reading the XML document is to transform it into another XML or HTML document, I would recommend using XSLT, instead.

If you want to test if an attribute exists, you can do something like this:

```
Dim attribute As XmlNode = personNode.Attributes.GetNamedItem("PersonId")
If attribute IsNot Nothing Then
    Dim personId As String = attribute.InnerText
End If
```

However, this would be much easier with serialization since the deserialized object would simply have null properties for any elements that didn't exist.

Comment: <EventTracker>
  <Item>
    <Events>
      <EventSub EventId='73' EventName='Orchestra' Description='0'>
        <Person PersonId='189323156' PersonName='Chandra' Address='Arunachal'></Track>
        <Person PersonId='189323172' PersonName='Sekhar' Address='Himachal'></Track>
      </EventSub>
      <EventSub EventId='74' EventName='Sports' Description='0'>
        <Person PersonId='89323156'  PersonName='Ram' Address='India'></Track>
        <Person PersonId='1893231' PersonName='Kumar' Address='Madhya Pradesh'></Track>
      </EventSub>
    </Events>
  </Item>
</EventTracker>

Comment: <EventTracker><StandardItem><Header1>Header1 Text</Header1> <Header2>Header2 Text</Header2></StandardItem><Item> <Events> <EventSub EventId='73' EventName='Orchestra' Description='0'> <Person PersonId='189323156' PersonName='Chandra' Address='Arunachal'/><Person PersonId='189323172' PersonName='Sekhar' Address='Himachal'/></EventSub> </Events> </Item> </EventTracker>. What could be the code if Header1 and Header2 are added like this at the top. Sorry to ask you again.

Comment: @user1407900 Why'd you post a second XML document?  It looks like my code would still process that one fine.

Comment: Please check my second comment.

Comment: @user1407900 Do you need to read the value of Header1 and 2, or just ignore them?

Comment: I have a small question. What if some attributes are missing and few new attributes are added. I will include all the possible list of attributes that comes in Person tag. How to skip the missing attributes in xml file?

Comment: @user1407900 I updated the answer to show an example of how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SelectSingleNode("XPath or NodeName")` and loop through the `Attributes.Item(index)` on that node. You can also, if you know the childnode name in advance, loop through `SelectSingleNode("XPath Or NodeName").SelectSingleNode("XPath or ChildName").Attributes.Item(index)`.